# Object has no attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so I have this code "Rock Paper Scissors" and I am getting an attribute error for class myApp object has no attribute 'myContainer1'. I am pretty clueless as of right now. Also if there is any other way that it can be improved that would also be a great help to me as well.

```
 from tkinter import * 
 import random
 def main():
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    class myApp:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.myParent = parent
            self.myParent = Frame(parent)
            self.myContainer1.pack()

            self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1, commmand = self.rockMove)
            self.button2.configure(text = "rock")
            self.button1.pack()
            self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.rockMove)

            self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = self.paperMove)
            self.button2.configure(text = "paper")
            self.button2.pack()
            self.button2.bind("<Button-2>", self.paperMove)

            self.button3 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = self.scissorsMove)
            self.button3.configure (text = "scissors")
            self.button3.pack()
            self.button3.bind("<Button-3>", self.scissorsMove)

            self.CompButton1 = Button(root)
            self.compButton1.configure(text = "rock", state = "disabled")
            self.compButton1.pack() 

            self.compButton2 = Button(root)
            self.compButton2.configure(text = "paper", state = "disabled")
            self.compButton2.pack()

            self.compButton3 = Button(root)
            self.compButton3.configure(text = "scissors", state = "disabled")
            self.compButton3.pack()

        def compRandom(self,event):
            self.compRandom["text"] = random.choice(options)
        def button1Click(self, event):
            if self.button1["text"] == "rock" and self.compButton1["text"] == "paper":
                return "You lose!"
            elif self.button1["text"] == "rock" and self.compbutton1["text"] == "rock":
                return "Draw!"
            else: "you win!"
        def rockMove(self, event):
            self.compRandom()
            self.button1Click()
        def button2Clck(self, event):
            if self.button2["text"] == "paper" and self.compButton2["text"] == "scissors":
                return "You lose!"
            elif self.button2["text"] == "paper" and self.compbutton2["text"] == "paper":
                return "Draw!"
            else: "you win!"
        def paperMove(self, event):
            self.compRandom()
            self.button2Click()
        def button3Click(self, event):
            if self.button3["text"] == "scissors" and self.compbutton3["text"] == "rock":
                return "you lose!"
            elif self.button3["text"] == "scissors" and self.compButton3["text"] == "scissors":
                return "Draw!"
            else: "you win!"
        def scissorsMove(slef, event):
            self.compRandom()
            self.button3Click()
    root = Tk()
    myapp = myApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error I am  experiencing I am not sure what is going on with the myContainer or myApp class. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the class??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 66, in main
    myapp = myApp(root)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 7, in __init__
    self.myContainer1.pack()
AttributeError: 'myApp' object has no attribute 'myContainer1'
```

Comment: Are you sure is not `self.myParent.pack()` ? (just sayin'... the code invites to think that)

Comment: Sorry, but the error is very clear - before `self.myContainer1.pack()`, `self.myContainer1` has not been defined. What did you expect for it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `myParent` is a typo of `myContainer1`.

Beside that, there are many typos.

- `button2` for `button1` in a line. `self.button2.configure(text = "rock")`
- `CompButton1` for `compButton1`
- `commmand` for `command`
- `slef` for `self`

And, the callback functions should have only one parameter: `self`.

---

`compRandom` is trying to assign item to the method. You may want to change some other widget instead of the `compRandom`.

```
def compRandom(self):
    self.compRandom["text"] = random.choice(options)
```